# php reference pass

Tags: php, reference

I have a problem with passing variables as reference in PHP.

I want to set `$grand_total` after:

```
$data = array('title' => 'blabla', 'value' => &$grand_total);

// Set after
$grand_total += 50;
```

This is running without a problem, but when I pass `$grand_total` var using a function, I get the error below:

> PHP Error was encountered Severity: 8192 Message: Call-time
>   pass-by-reference has been deprecated Filename:
>   controllers/checkout.php Line Number: 131

I'm passing the variable like this:

```
$data = array('title' => 'blabla', 'value' => price(&$grand_total));

// Set after
$grand_total += 50;
```

I must use the `price()` function.

Can anyone help me?

I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please post the `price()` function - what does it return?

Comment: the price function return string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work perfectly fine for you

```
    $grand_total = 10;
    function &price($value)
    {
        $value += 10;
        return $value ;
    }
    $grand_total = price($grand_total);
    $data = array('title' => 'blabla', 'value' =>$grand_total);
    $grand_total += 50;
    var_dump($grand_total)
```

Output

```
    int 70
```

For more Information

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 0):

Without the function its a bit difficult. We don't know what is on line "131"

Look to your php.ini

```
allow_call_time_pass_reference = On
```

If this parameter is set to off its not working. But general its deprecated in PHP 5 to call the time function with a reference ("&$grand_total"). Call the function without the reference or assign the reference in your function to another variable and use the variable not the reference.

Comment: Note that `allow_call_time_pass_reference` has been **removed** from PHP 5.4, anybody still relying on this is stuck at 5.3 indefinitely.